# What is google oauth consent screen values?

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-developers-console

While registering new oauth client on Google its oauth consent screen is demanding private policy url , app homepage url and authorized url .i am developing on localhost how to get them

Answer (score 6):

For localhost, you don't need a privacy policy URL, but will need it if you publish your application.

Your authorised redirect will normally show in the error message when Google OAuth fails, but will probably be `http://localhost/signin-google`, You may need to include your port number if you are debugging.

Answer (score 3):

When creating a new project on Google developer console there are some values that you will need to fill out.

> **About the consent screen**
>   The consent screen tells your users who is requesting access to their data and what kind of data you're asking to access.
>
> **OAuth Developer Verification**
>   To protect you and your users, your consent screen may need to be verified by Google. Without verification, your users will see an additional page indicating that your app is not verified by Google. Learn more
>
> **Verification is required if:**
>   Your application type is public, and
>   You add a sensitive scope
>   Verification may take several days to complete. You will receive email updates as it's processed.
>
> **Saving without publishing**
>   Even though your consent screen is unpublished, you can still test your application with users with the following limitations:

Required values

> Application Homepage link
>   Shown on the consent screen. Must be hosted on an Authorized Domain.
>
> Application Privacy Policy link
>   Shown on the consent screen. Must be hosted on an Authorized Domain.

If this is only your own application and will you will still have to set a location for these.   If you have to verify the application you will need to ensure that these are valid values.   However if you are just testing this currently localhost then you can set them to any valid url

**Unverified apps**

I know that you mentioned this will be a localhost app.  However you need to be aware that depending upon which scopes you request you may still be required to verify your application to use it [verified](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7454865?hl=en&ref_topic=7013279) after a number of requests.

> Sensitive scopes are limited to 100 grant requests before verification is required
>   Users see an additional page indicating that your app is not verified by Google
>   Let us know what you think about our OAuth experience.

Comment: Verification takes approx 1-2 months. Isn't there any faster way to have your consent screen verified? Should we call google support?

Comment: if you have a number for google support sure go for it i have never seen a google support number